# PHP - DynamoDB - Unique key

Tags: php, mysql, database, nosql, amazon-dynamodb

I am switching my database from MySQL to dynamo and I'm reading everywhere that Dynamo does not support auto-increment and has no concept of queuing writes. If that is the case, what is the best approach to ensure that my keys are unique no matter how many processes are hitting the database at the same time?

I thought of using epoch time stamp, but that does not guarantee uniqueness.

Comment: Universally unique identifier (uuid) - http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out a unique id mechanism depending on your needs.
Here is a [link with some options in php](http://phpgoogle.blogspot.co.il/2007/08/four-ways-to-generate-unique-id-by-php.html).

You can also read about [twitter snowflake](https://github.com/twitter/snowflake) unique id generator.

If session handling is your problem this [post from AWS](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/04/scalable-session-handling-in-php-using-amazon-dynamodb.html) might help.

I have some areas in my db that aren't write intensive so I use DynamoDB table to mimic auto-increment numbers using AttributeAction ADD 1.

Answer (score -1):

DynamoDB is a key-value storage, and it is impossible to have 2 records with the same primary key. But you need to be carefull because without additional checks on `put` you could overwrite you old record.

To avoid this you could use `attribute_not_exists` condition expression to ensure that there is no other record with the same id.

For other columns there is no build-in mechanism to ensure uniqueness, but you could implement it by yourself.

In short you need to create several records for each time, first to save you payload and one to handle single unique index. Also it would be required to add conditional expression each time when you insert new or update the record.

e.g. we have a `user` table and we want to ensure id and email. Here how our records will looks like

```
{
  pk: 'some-user-id',
  record_type: 'record'
  email: 'some@some.com'
}
{
  pk: 'unique-index#some@some.com',
  record_type: 'unique-index'
}
```

Each time when you would insert new user to db, you would need to insert both records using DynamoDB write transaction and check that there is no any other record with the same `pk`, for both of them.

Here is [my article](https://medium.com/@ihar.kryvanos/unique-indexes-in-dynamodb-7c76461ae944) on how. You could find detailed description and wide code examples there